# Move data from one table to another in the same Database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I realize this question has been asked before, but nothing I've read really answers my question.

I have a table with millions of rows of data that is used in multiple queries a day. I want to move the majority of the data to another table with the same schema. The second table will be an "archive" table.

I would like a list of options to archive data, so I can present them to my boss. So far I'm considering an insert into select statement, SQLBulkCopy in a C# console application, and I'm starting to dig in to SSIS to see what it can do. I plan on doing this over a weekend or multiple weekends.

- The table has an ID as the primary key
- The table also has a few foreign key constraints

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You mention foreign key constraints. Is the expectation that you will eventually have to delete the archived data from the original table?

Comment: Yes I will delete the data from the original table once I have it in the new table. But I still need access to the archived data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that this is for SQL Server. In that case, [partitioned tables](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190787.aspx) might be an additional option. Otherwise I'd always go for a `INSERT ... SELECT` run by a job in SQL Server, or - if you can't run it directly in SQL Server - create a stored procedure and run it through a little C# tool that you schedule.

Comment: Yes I'm using SQL Server 2012. I'll look in to partitioned tables. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try execute something like

```
CREATE TABLE mynewtable as select * from myoldtable where any_filter..;
```

You could create new table with data copy with one instruction on most database engines.

Use this, in case of SQL Server 2008

```
Select * into new_table  from  old_table
```

Comment: The first is only a one-shot thing, right? It would create a snapshot. If he doesn't want to create a new table every time, the second would be better.

Comment: Right, it will be a copy of data.

Comment: If I did a insert into select statement would it be better to do batches of data instead of trying it all at once?

Comment: Doesn't matter. Doing it at once might even be faster than doing chunks. The statement is directly executed by the DB engine, so it should be as fast as it gets.

Comment: 'insert select' or 'create table as select' is always fastest way to copy data. You dont need to move your data somewhere out of database itself, just make a copy. There's no big difference between 'insert select' or 'create table as select' (second locks database dictionary while copying)

Answer (score 0):

In the event that you have a set data archive interval, you may be able to leverage the partition-to-archive solution described in the following article.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/felixmar/archive/2011/02/14/partitioning-amp-archiving-tables-in-sql-server-part-1-the-basics.aspx

Our team has leveraged a similar partition / archive solution in the past with good success.

Regards,